# WebView with tabs Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, webview

I want create the WebView app with Tabs.
I don't like TabbedPage. I need sample with ListView.
I want create tabs based on ListView.
I new in Xamarin Forms. Help me please.
Can you give me a sample?

Thank you in advance.
Best wishes!

With this code, I create a new tab on the list.
[image]

I can't select the last item on the list.
TabsList.SelectedItem = _tabs[selector]; This is not working.

I also can't change the item I've selected in the list when I upload a page to WebView.

[image]

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  "Can you give me a sample?" is not an appropriate question for SO.

Comment: What do you mean by tabs based on ListView? Can you please add a picture to describe what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want open sites to appear on the list. So you can remove the site from the list and add it. At the same time, you can change the selected item in the list.

Comment: A picture would be better to describe your requirement. And show us what you have tried so far. The document of [listView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/) is here.

Comment: I need to figure out how to select the last item on the list. And how to change the chosen one.

Comment: Is the TabList a listView? Can you please provide us [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?